Which is better to prolong li-ion battery life: float charged at 80% SoC or cycle between 20% - 80% SoC?
We are designing a device that draws <0.2 mA on average with surge of 50 ~ 500 mA for several milliseconds every 5 minutes. The device will be powered by a large capacity Li-ion battery (26650, 5000 mAh@1C), with external AC adapter either constantly connected, or only connected if battery voltage drops below 3.x V (3.6 V for now, TBD).
The overall goal is to prolong the life of Li-ion battery as long as possible in both use cases. In a previous design, battery was float charged at 4.2 V. That turned out a very bad idea. After 2 ~ 3 years of operations with external AC adapters constantly connected, battery would start to die completely.
The planned strategies are two folds:

terminate charging at a lower voltage, either 4.1 V or even lower such as 4.0 V if necessary. Some readily available Li-ion battery management IC such as BQ24079 from TI can terminate charging at 4.1 V, but will constantly recharge battery if voltage drops below 4.0 V.
design a better recharge routine.

So my question is, will disable recharging of battery until voltage drops below a much lower voltage such as 3.6 V be better for battery life?
Typically this kind of device is powered by Li-SCL2 batteries that can last up to 10 years. But those battery are expensive to source and replace. If we can push the life of li-ion battery over 10 years, then Li-ion battery can be a more cost-effective alternative. In a previous post, the designer reported little degradation of battery after 12 years float charge around 25% SoC. But it is not practical for us to only use 25% of battery capacity.
Please advise, thanks.

An AC adaptor is not a proper battery charger so, what did you expect? Or maybe you meant an AC adaptor feeding the battery via a proper charger circuit? But, from the rest of your question you appear not to have used a proper charger circuit.

My bad, I should have stated more clearly. The battery charging is managed by BQ24075, AC adapter is not directly connected to battery. I haven't come across any AC adapter with 4.2V output so far. So I cannot even if I wanted to :)

There are some documents floating around on how NASA handles this on satellites; I would do what they do. IIrc the lower the SOC you can maintain the better. I don't think you need to cycle it. 50% should give you an extremely long life.

Why is it not practical to keep the device at 25% SOC? One of your paradigms will have it at that point sometimes. What happens if you lose power right then?

@Drew the reason it is not practical to use only 25% capacity is we have to deal with two different use cases: with external AC adapters connected all the time or only when necessary. If we only charge to %25 then device cannot run long enough if AC adapter is removed. In theory we can differentiate two use cases in firmware and deal with differently, but that will get complicated quickly.

@ZhiyongLi Ok, that's fine. You just need to state that limitation somewhere. You can  use more battery to get a longer operating life (lower SOC, lower DOD). You can also use it to get larger capacity. To get both you need a battery that's larger still.

LiFePO4 is worth considering, it's easily available and almost as cheap as regular Li-ion, while being safer and longer life. Voltage is lower though, which may be an issue.

The cycle induced damage in batteries happens when the ions move around. Think of it like two sponges between which you move an amount of water, as a very crude metaphor. Only that the "empty" sponge won't have air to fill the voids but vacuum. So the empty sponge will be crushed, whereas the full sponge will be larger. Loading and unloading the ions exerts a lot of such structural pressure, and this is what damages the material as you charge and discharge many times. Eventually the ion movement will be incomplete and this is what you experience as reduced charge capacity.
If you float charge, you avoid this entirely. Though ideally, you float charge at an intermediate charge state like 50%. 80% is ok too, but don't go over the flat part of the voltage curve. If I recall correctly, most Li ion batteries are stored at something like 20% SoC for long term.
If you are interested in having very long life, you should not cycle it at all and never go near the fully charged/discharged states.

Does this mean I should keep my phone at 50% charged to prolong battery life?

@findwindow: sure, if you can get your phone to be always connected to a charger, without exception. at which point your phone wouldn't need a battery (i assume the use-case in the OP is for emergency backup power)

If it was constantly connected to a charger, it wouldn't get to 50%. Sounds like the idea is to not let battery level fluctuate too much to prolong its life?

@findwindow some OS allow you specify max charge state. In that case, the charging will be suspended when max is hit and will then float around that level, as long as the charger remains available.

@findwindow your device will almost certainly be obsolete long before the difference in battery life between 50% and 80% SOC becomes relevant.


You should always use power from the AC adapter preferentially over power from the battery when possible. Cycling the battery ages it somewhat.
You should keep the battery at a low state of charge. The lower the better.

You have said that keeping a steady 25% SOC is not practical for your application. If you can't maintain a certain SOC, ask yourself why. You will need to balance that reason against your need for a longer calendar lifespan of the system.
There are many papers on this subject. Here's one that I found:
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/2.0411609jes
Relevant chart:


Thanks for your answer and link to literature. Power path is managed by the charging IC BQ2407X, when an external AC adapter is connected, power is primarily drawn from AC adapter unless it cannot sustain surge current. The voltage drop in battery when an AC adapter is connected is mostly caused by self-discharge.

Good information here. In particular I learn that very low SoC do not seem to be detrimental.

@tobalt: Deep discharge is bad.

@Michael Correct, but it's important to note that 0% SOC is not deep discharge.

@Drew: How do we even define 0% SoC? Shouldn’t that be where all Electricity has been extracted, i.e. full deep discharge? And 100% basically where it’s almost exploding.

@Michael That is not even close to how it is defined LOL. The battery is designed to be used in a certain voltage range. The top of this range is 100%, the bottom is 0%.

@Drew: Yes, but charging and discharging cut-off voltages are a pretty arbitrary compromise between longevity and (initial) capacity, no? One manufacturer might specify 0% as 3.2V and 100% as 4.1V while the other one goes from 2.5V to 4.2V with corresponding longevity and capacities.

@Michael Perhaps, but we are discussing lithium ion batteries in general. 0% would not be specified at a point which damages the battery.
